# Is it possible or not to write a Chrome extension what communicates with a dedicated server?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

NPAPI is dead at least is dying especially in Chrome.

I must find a way to create a browser extension which communicates with a dedicated server using https. I suppose this will be done in JavaScript with or without JQuery. I am pretty new in the concept, so please feel free to edit if my terminology is not clear.

As far I see this is very similar as doing crossdomain communication within one page, so it raises security issues. I've tried to get the answer, but what've found so far is contradictory to believe.

This extension must be working in *any* page, not only that pages (servers) which enable cross domain. I would like to ask the user's permission, not the server's permission.

Answer (score -1):

It should be possible, however it might be required for the server to allow the Cross domain request by sending an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: REQUESTING_DOMAIN.TLD` (or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`) header

Comment: Do you mean: The server who is serving the page?. I am editing my question,

Comment: The dedicated server serving the the data needs to send these headers

Comment: I would like to send data from _any_ page (served by any server) using script in my extension to a dedicated host.

Comment: In that case, let your server send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, this allows the ajax to do its work cross domain.